# How to upload an MP3 file to Firebase-Firestore database with React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I actually have two questions here, the first is about my code. the second is about how to upload mp3 files to the Firestore cloud data base through react.

The following code should be a form that adds new documents easily inside the cloud storage collection:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import db from '../index';

const AddSongs = () => {
    const [song, setSong] = useState('');
    const [artist, setArtist] = useState('');
    const [src, setSrc] = useState('');


    const inSubmit = (e) =>{

        e.preventDefault();

        let songBase = db.collection('songs');
        let data = {song, artist, src}

        songBase
            .add(data)

    }


    return ( 
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={inSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Add Your Track
                </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the track" value={song} onChange={e => 
                 setSong(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the artist" value={artist} onChange={e => 
                 setArtist(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="file" value={src} onChange={e => setSrc(e.target.value)} />
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="add it" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AddSongs;
```

and the docs are added to the cloud storage successfully as normal docs with properties which are song, artist and src.
and this is another code which should then take the current data inside the collection and renders it to a jsx div

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import db from '../index';

const SongList = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    let songbase = db.collection('songs')

    songbase.onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
            setList([...list, {song: doc.song, artist: doc.artist, src: doc.src, id: Math.random(0,1)}])
        })
    })

    const renderedList = list.length ? (list.map(songItem =>{
        return(
            <div key={songItem.id}>
                <span>{songItem.song}</span>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src={songItem.src} type="audio/mpeg" />
                </audio>
                <span>{songItem.artist}</span>
            </div>
        )
    })) : (<h1>nope !</h1>)
    return ( 
        <div>
            {renderedList}
        </div>
     );
}

export default SongList;
```

And then what happens here is that the songItem (that gets rendered inside an empty jsx) repeats itself endlessly and keeps scrolling down.. !

The second question is how to add mp3 files to the firebase cloud storage from my local device, because the (src) adds the mp3 file path as a string in the doc properties, example : C:\fakepath\Black Sabbath - Falling off the Edge of the World (With Lyrics).mp3.

Sorry for the long question, your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `react-firebase-file-uploader` package.

It consist of props like `storageRef - A reference to the firebase storage folder, where the file should be saved.`

`onUploadStart, onProgress, onUploadSuccess, onUploadError, filename, metadata, randomizeFilename, maxHeight, maxWidth` and many other useful props.

Here's the reference link for more details. [Click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-file-uploader)

Comment: the documentation wasn't pretty helpful as it was in pretty different and old-modeled code, I would appreciate it if you tell me how can I apply it to this code. and also if you can help with the endless map loop that keeps repeating itself. It would be great.